# Notebook - Keyboard Shortcuts: Ctrl-K, Ctrl-J (Not Working)

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I can't get <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to move between cells in the notebook, when I'm in command mode.

I'm running on a Mac OS X (Chrome browser).

However, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> works. I'm assuming it's an error with the documentation?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several keyboard shortcuts are common between *Jupyter* and *Datalab*. You may find it helpful to view the *Jupyter* keyboard shortcut help dialog that is accessible within a datalab notebook. To open the *Jupyter* keyboard shortcut help dialog, open a datalab notebook, then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter command mode, then press <kbd>H</kbd>.

[image: Jupyter help]

Comment: Yes, that's helpful - I didn't realize there was an additional help document.  As you pointed out, ESC then h.  And, on the MAC, it gives the option and cmd translations, which appear to work correctly.